# Assigning a prop value to data in a Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template>
    <div class="container p-2">
        <form id="Lookup">
            <div class="row p-2">
                <div class="col-12 input-group ">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode"   :placeholder="initial" v-model="location" class="form-control p-3"><div class="input-group-append"><i class="material-icons input-group-text" @click="$emit('findlocation', location)">location_searching</i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props: ['initial'],
        data: function () {
            return {
              location : this.initial
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The above is my Vue Component which is passed a string value called initial
This value is passed from the template below

```
<practicesearch-component @findlocation="getlocation" :initial=postalTown" />
```

where postalTown is a data property of the main vue

but instead of getting the string value of postalTown in location I get

> function String() { [native code] }

the prop initial in the Vue Component shows the correct string value but location has been assigned a function 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When Vue initializes your component, the `data` function does not have access to the View Model `this`. You can use the mounted hook to assign the value

```
export default {
    props: ['initial'],
    data: () => ({
        location: undefined
    }),
    mounted() {
        this.location = this.initial;
    }
}
```

#### **Note** that this way, whenever `initial` changes in the parent, **`location` will not be updated**.

Here is a quick sample:

```js
Vue.productionTip = false;
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div class="child">
    Child component:
    <br/>
    location: {{ location }}
    <br/>
    initial: {{ initial }}
  </div>
  `,
  props: { initial: String },
  data: () => ({ location: undefined }),
  mounted () {
    this.location = this.initial;
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div class="parent">
    Parent Component
    <br/>
    location: {{ location }}
    <child :initial="location" />
  </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({ location: 'US' })
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: darkgray;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid 1px black;
  color: white;
}

.child {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid 1px black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5229157/daniel-orme%c3%b1o?tab=profile it's working, thank you, how can we avoid the "whenever initial changes in the parent, location will not be updated" ?

Answer (score 0):

After much analysis I found the problem that was causing this behaviour.

```
<practicesearch-component @findlocation="getlocation" :initial=postalTown" />
```

postalTown in the above was not set initially in the Vue instance but within mounted therefore the component was being passed an uninitialised string object and not the initialised value of postalTown

I added the :key attribute on postalTown as below which causes the component to re-render with the initialised value of postalTown
Perhaps this is not the best option but it works

```
<practicesearch-component @findlocation="getlocation" :key=postalTown :initial=postalTown ></practicesearch-component>
```

Comment: Also, you should use quotes to wrap the value of key and initial. (:key="postalTown" etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Daniel Ormeño answer

If you are having trouble with updating data properties if prop from parent changes, you can use watch.

```
...

      props: ['initial'],
      data: () => ({
        location: null
      }),
 
      watch: { 
        initial: function(newVal) {
          this.location = newVal
        }
      },

 ...
```

This way every time parent's input prop changes, child watches for prop change and sets your location, whether it's initial or updated data.